# Read Json string using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a json string as given below.

```
$json='        {
    "code":  0,
    "ms":  "success",
    "dt":  {
             "st":  1,
             "mns":  [
                              "@{name=product 1 - w; att=response_time; st=1; time=2020-08-21T14:18:03-0400; locations=System.Object[]; attN=RESPONSETIME; mt=PORT; attL=Response Time; attribute_value=67; unit=ms; monitor_id=12}",
                              "@{name=product 2 - w; att=response_time; st=1; time=2020-08-21T14:18:03-0400; locations=System.Object[]; attN=RESPONSETIME; mt=PORT; attL=Response Time; attribute_value=70; unit=ms; monitor_id=23}",
                              "@{name=product 3 - w; att=response_time; st=1; time=2020-08-21T14:18:03-0400; locations=System.Object[]; attN=RESPONSETIME; mt=PORT; attL=Response Time; attribute_value=66; unit=ms; monitor_id=24}",
                              "@{st=5; name=product 4 - w; mt=PORT; monitor_id=35}"
                          ],
             "gd":  "12345",
             "gn":  "group_name 5 - w"
         }
}'
```

I tried to read the status value given under "mns" using the below code

```
    $jsonobject= ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
    foreach ($mn in $jsonobject.dt.mns)
     {
      $mndata=ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $mn
      Write-Host $mndata["st"]
     }
```

But i'm not able to retrieve the value of $mndata["st"] .

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the input json?

Comment: No, it is a response i get

Comment: Your problem is that your mns records is strings and not Json. So either your parse it as a string or you update it to be proper json format.

Comment: I cannot update the json because it is a WEBREQUEST response. What you meant by parse as  a string. You mean to use some REGEX?. I

Comment: @tjdoubts How did you obtain it? Using `Invoke-WebRequest/Invoke-RestMethod`? Please show us the exact command you run (sans URL) to get that exact JSON string

Comment: @Mathias It is Invoke-RestMethod . All the below answers are working

Answer (score 2):

`ConvertFrom-StringData` expects key-value pairs on separate lines, so you will have to re-format the input string a bit first:

```
foreach ($mn in $jsonobject.dt.mns)
{
  $multiLine = $mn.Trim('@{};') -replace ';\s*',"`r`n"
  $mndata = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $multiLine
  Write-Host $mndata["st"]
}
```

---

Given the format of the strings (and the `locations=System.Object[]` pair), it appears that the original JSON might have been produced by `ConvertTo-Json` with an insufficient `-Depth` parameter, you might have an easier time solving this problem by going back and fixing that wherever you get this data from

Answer (score 1):

Since the mns is not proper json you need to treat it like a string.

```
$jsonobject= ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json

foreach ($mn in $jsonobject.dt.mns)
{
    Write-Output ($mn | Select-String -Pattern 'st=(\d+)').Matches.Groups[1].Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `ConvertFrom-StringData` works with key-value pairs separated by a new line. On each iterations, your only value is (for the first index) key : `@{name`, value : `product 1 - w; att=response_time; st=1; time=2020-08-21T14:18:03-0400; locations=System.Object[]; attN=RESPONSETIME; mt=PORT; attL=Response Time; attribute_value=67; unit=ms; monitor_id=12}`.

I don't know the `@{key1=value1; key2=value2}` format, but you can modify it to get a usable format. `$mn.trim("@{}")` should do the job to remove the surrounding `@{` and `}`.

Then, you want to use newlines instead of `;` so `ConvertFrom-StringData` can correctly convert the datas. You can use `.Replace(";", [Environment]::NewLine)`

```
foreach ($mn in $jsonobject.dt.mns)
 {
     $mndata = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $mn.trim("@{}").Replace(";", [Environment]::NewLine)
     Write-Host $mndata["st"]
 }
```

This outputs :

> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$jsonobject= $json | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($mn in $jsonobject.dt.mns)
{
    $stringToBeLocated = "st="
    $mnStValueIndex = $mn.IndexOf($stringToBeLocated)
    $mnStValue = $mn.Substring($mnStValueIndex+$stringToBeLocated.Length, 1)
    Write-Output $mnStValue
}
```

Output:

[image]